# Get latest entry by date (year) and add Value to field from this row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I will do the following:

Run a Query that return me the latest record from current year take a field from that record.

This is may Tabel I used for this:

```
ID(int,PK)    FremdID(int)    Erstellung(datetime)      Number(int)
1             10              2019-05-31 09:15:41.003   1
2             11              2019-05-31 09:15:42.154   3
```

So if I run the query it should return Row with index 2 because we are in year 2019 and that is the latest entry from 2019.

If we are now in 2020 then the query should not return any row becuase there is no entry for 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend:

```
SELECT TOP(1) t.*
FROM #Table t
WHERE Erstellung >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1)
ORDER BY Erstellung DESC;
```

I recommend this because it is index compatible.  It can take advantage of an index on `(Erstellung DESC)`.

If you use a function like `YEAR(Erstellung)` in the `WHERE` clause, the index will not be used.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
SELECT a.Number 
FROM [YourTable] a
JOIN (SELECT MAX(Erstellung) AS Erstellung
      FROM [YourTable]
      WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,Erstellung) = DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())
      ) b ON a.Erstellung = b.Erstellung
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that get me the last row. But only the datetime field, I need the Number field

Comment: Update the answer. You can use subqueries for this too